# Structure objects that share the same common names

Tags: javascript, polymorphism

I have simplified my problem below but I have 2 objects which each implement a `print` and `send` function. The object used is decided based on some other behaviour in the application. Javascript doesnt have any interfaces for me to define the function and achieve polyporphism

I want to remove the boilerplate code of providing the same `return` statement for every object. Is there an easier way for me to do this so if I introduce a new object it implements the `print` and `send` functions

```
Object1 = function() {

   var _print = function(text){
    console.log(text)
   }

   var _send = function(){
    $.ajax("/object1/", "post");
   }

    return {
        print: _print,
        send : _send

    };
};


Object2 = function() {

   var _print = function(text){
    console.log("Your Account Id is " + text)
   }

      var _send = function(){
    $.ajax("/object2/", "post");
   }

    return {
        print: _print
        send : _send

    };
};
```

Comment: Use a prototype method for `send` and have an instance variable for the URL?

Comment: Your code won't work as posted, because you never define `_print`. (Probably just a transcription error.)

Comment: Google "object oriented programming in Javascript"